# pygame program variable be used before it assignment

Tags: python, pygame

When I read program On this page  http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter8.html

on line 139 , the variable `sObj['movex']`

`sObj['movex']` is used before its assignment，but this program can run correctly，why？

Comment: And thank you the people first answer my question, i am sorry for you delete,english is not my first language，maybe i can't say clearly my view，sorry ，my fault。

Comment: @user2988776 No worries, the regular users on StackOverflow are here to make correct edits to your post (if it is not understandable enough) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the extract from the code

```
# move all the squirrels
for sObj in squirrelObjs:
    # move the squirrel, and adjust for their bounce
    sObj['x'] += sObj['movex']
    sObj['y'] += sObj['movey']
```

Notice that you are actually defining & assigning the variable `sObj` at the start of the `for` loop! `sObj` gets assigned a new variable as per the `for` construct & so the program will give no errors due to this.

Also note, that `sObj` is just another variable "name" given to the *object* in `squirrels`. Thus, `sObj` is nothing but an alias to iterate over each of the objects (serially) in the `squirrels`.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Just note the last 2 lines of my updated answer.